# The Straw Picking Game: Helping the computer learn from its' mistakes?

Tags: java

So I have the game already programmed. You take turns against the computer picking 1-3 straws and the point of the game is to leave the opponent with 1 straw. That entire section works, but now I have to program the Computer to get smarter through consecutive play.

I'm not entirely sure how this is done, however. The way it was explained to me was that you have 4 "cups", which I assume are arrays. Each cup contains the moves, (1, 2, 3). During the computer's turn it randomly picks a cup and randomly chooses one of the three moves. If that move doesn't work then it removes it from the cup.

After several games the computer should become unbeatable.I'm going to keep working on this but I'm having a lot of trouble. I've been at it for a couple hours now so I'll just post the raw code without my broken parts.

EDIT: I've added the Cup class at the bottom.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Nim
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
  Random r = new Random();
  Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
  String reply;

  int straws, cupNum, prevCupNum, prevComputerMove, 
      computerMove, humanMove, gameNumber = 0, humanWin = 0;

  // create an array of four cups
  Cup[] cup = new Cup[4];
  for (int i = 0; i < cup.length; i++)
     cup[i] = new Cup();


  System.out.println("Let's play Nim");
  System.out.println();
  do
  {
     gameNumber++;
     straws = r.nextInt(11) + 10;  
     // add 1 if necessary so computer nevers starts in losing config       
     if (straws%4 == 1)
        straws++;
     System.out.println("Straws to start = " + straws);
     System.out.println();

     // set to -1 to indicate just starting so no previous move
     prevCupNum = -1;      // no prev move so init to -1
     prevComputerMove = -1;

     do
     {
        cupNum = straws%4;   // get cup number

        // if cup is empty, then use 1 for move
        if (cup[cupNum].count() == 0)  // cup empty then move = 1
           computerMove = 1;   
        else
           computerMove = cup[cupNum].select(); // get move from cup



        /*MISSING CODE
        If cup is cup number 1, then remove the previous move
        from the previous cup unless already empty*/

        System.out.println
           ("Computer picks up " + computerMove + " straws");
        straws = straws - computerMove;
        if (straws < 0)
           straws = 0;
        System.out.println(straws + " left");
        System.out.println();

        // save this move so it can be removed later if necessary
        prevCupNum = cupNum;
        prevComputerMove = computerMove;

        if (straws == 0)
        {
           System.out.println("Wow.  You win!");
           humanWin++;

           /* MISSING CODE
            Remove last move computer made from cup*/
        }
        else  // get move from human
        {
           System.out.println();
           do
           {
              System.out.print("Your move: enter ");

              if (straws == 1)
                 System.out.println("1");
              else
              if (straws == 2)
                 System.out.println("1 or 2");
              else
              if (straws >= 3)
                 System.out.println("1, 2, or 3"); 
              humanMove = kb.nextInt();
           } while
              (humanMove > 3 || humanMove < 1 || straws - humanMove < 0);

           straws = straws - humanMove;
           System.out.println(straws + " left");
           if (straws == 0)
           {   
              System.out.println();
              System.out.println("Ha, ha.  You lose!");
           }
        }
     } while (straws > 0);


     System.out.println
        ("Score: Human " + humanWin + "   Computer " + 
         (gameNumber - humanWin));

     if (kb.hasNextLine())   // get rid of stray newline
        kb.nextLine();
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println("Want to play another game?  Hit enter.");
     System.out.println
        ("Or are you too CHICKEN? In that case, type in quit.");
     reply = kb.nextLine();
     reply = reply.trim();
     if (reply.length() > 4)  // require only 1st 4 to be quit
        reply = reply.substring(0, 4);

 } 
while (!reply.toLowerCase().equals("quit"));
   }
public class Cup
{
   ArrayList<Integer> c = new ArrayList<Integer>();

   public Cup()
   {
      c.add(1);
      c.add(2);
      c.add(3);
   }
   //-----------------------
   public int count()
   {
      return c.size();
   }
   //-----------------------
   public int select()
   {
      // random is a static method in Math that returns a double
      // value greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.
      int index = (int)(c.size()*Math.random());
      return c.get(index);
   }
   //-----------------------
   public void remove(Integer move)
   {
         c.remove(move);
   }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. However as it stands your question might get closed as too broad/primarily opinion based (I hope not).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't understand the 'cup' strategy. There is a much simpler strategy to force the machine to learn through play, however. As it plays, record the number of straws it leaves after its turn. If it loses then ensure that it doesn't leave that many straws in turns in subsequent games.

Your code would look something like:

```
class AI_Player {
    private final Set<Integer> losingMoves = new HashSet<>();
    private final Set<Integer> currentGameMoves = new HashSet<>();

    public void startGame() {
        currentGameMoves.clear();
    }

    public int nextMove(int strawsRemaining) {
        List<Integer> possibleMoves = Stream.of(1, 2, 3)
            .filter(move -> move < strawsRemaining)
            .filter(move -> !losingMoves.contains(strawsRemaining - move))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        int move = possibleMoves.get(Random.nextInt(possibleMoves.size()));
        currentGameMoves.add(strawsRemaining - move);
        return move;
    }

    public void registerLoss() {
        losingMoves.addAll(currentGameMoves);
    }

    public void registerWin() {
        losingMoves.removeAll(currentGameMoves);
    }
}
```

This uses Java 8 streams but it's fairly trivial to convert if you haven't used them yet.